# Google Analytics Admin API - How would I use access.binding.create?

Tags: python, analytics, admin, google-analytics-4

As title

google remove  **userlinks**  from  Admin API v1 Alpha at 2023/06

replace by **AccessBindings**

I need to use python to give GA permissions to the Google account and remove it

This is my original code

```
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from datetime import datetime
import traceback
import sys

# Set up credentials and build the Analytics Admin API client

credentials = Credentials.from_service_account_file('../account_credentials.json')
analytics = build('analyticsadmin', 'v1alpha', credentials=credentials)

def GA_create(account_ID,usermails,roles):
    for N in range(len(usermails)):
        user_link = {
        'directRoles': [f'predefinedRoles/{roles[N]}'],
        'emailAddress': usermails[N]
        }

        response = analytics.accounts().userLinks().create(
            name=f"accounts/{account_ID}",
            body=user_link
        ).execute()

  

if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:

        args = sys.argv
        account_ID = args[1]
        # Use comma to split
        usermails = args[2].split(',')
        # Use comma to split ,  Roles valid values: viewer/analyst/editor/admin/no-cost-data/no-revenue-data
        roles = args[3].split(',')

        GA_create(account_ID,usermails,roles)

    except Exception as e:
        print("error:", str(e))

        tb = traceback.extract_tb(e.__traceback__)
        print(tb)
```

I change userlinks to AccessBindings like this

```
def GA_create(account_ID,usermails,roles):
    for N in range(len(usermails)):
        user_link = {
        'directRoles': [f'predefinedRoles/{roles[N]}'],
        'emailAddress': usermails[N]
        }

        response = analytics.accounts().accessBindings().create(
            name=f"accounts/{account_ID}/AccessBindings/100",
            body=user_link
        ).execute()
```

I got an error: Got an unexpected keyword argument name

How would I edit the code to enable use AccessBindings create , delete , list?

Comment: I resolved the create , But I can't use delete :(